# Datatype Datetime value Initialization

Tags: c#

I am updating the a table with different values and in that one date datatype also there.

After updating the table I am initializing the variables to 0 and spaces based on the datatypes - but I am unable to initialize Datetime Datatype.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: To help you we need to know, are you using ADO.NET 2.0, Linq-to-Sql, Entity Framework? That way we could help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can get initialize value for every value type by "default" keyword

```
DateTime a = default(DateTime);
```

Comment: `default(type)` works for any type, not just value-types. `default(string)` will give you `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the values to `default(type)` implicitly - for DateTime: `default(DateTime)`.

For database operations, you would probably be better of with the `SqlDateTime` type as the minimal or maximal values of `DateTime` usually cannot be stored in databases as date types.

Initialization:

```
string connString = "...";
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO Test(col1, col2) VALUES (@col1, @col2)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ""; // or .Value=DBNull.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.DateTime).SqlValue = default(SqlDateTime); // or .Value=DBNull.Value;
    }
}
```

You can initialize all the values to DBNull.Value

Comment: Can u help to write the sql comamnd how to do this .. thanking u very much.

Comment: You can use the code in my updated post. Also, if the column in a table is nullable, you could initiate the values with the DBNUll as noted in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Set the DateTime to null with this code:

```
DateTime? datetime;
```

Since DateTime is a struct, not a class, you get a DateTime object, not a reference, when you declare a field or variable of that type. And, in the same way as an int cannot be null, so can this DateTime object never be null, because it's not a reference.

Adding the question mark turns it into a nullable type, which means that either it is a DateTime object, or it is null.

Finally when using the value, assign the value to an DateTime:

```
if(datetime.hasvalue)
{    
DateTime dt = datetime.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old...but still relevant.
Creating a new DateTime variable

```
DateTime dDate = new DateTime();
```

will give it an initial value of {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}...which **may** be what you want.

MSSQL will give you a range error if dates are outside the range of January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999 
[datetime TSQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
In the case of database data...I think a null date is better than a wrong date.
Anyway...one way to initialize a date to a value is simply:

```
DateTime dDate = new DateTime(1980,01,01);
```

All kinds of overloads on this:[DateTime Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2#formatting-03)